# Spring boot test configuration not override normal configuration well

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have a spring boot application with configuation like this:

**src/main/resources/application.yml:**

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://10.254.102.12:1111/eureka/
```

In my unit test cases, I want to set eureka instance name and change the logging level.
**src/test/resources/application.yml:**

```
eureka:
  instance:
    appname: item-client-test

logging:
  level: debug
```

But when I added these additional settings those former settings seems to not work any more. The eureka serviceUrl fallback to default loclahost:8761, so my test failed. When I added my custom eureka serviceUrl to `src/test/resources/application.yml`, my test goes well.

So I am confused about is this a bug of spring boot or I was not using the right way for my configuration?

Comment: AFAIK, spring boot doesn't merge them. It uses the most specific one, the test one.

Comment: Does it merge proproties files?

Comment: No, it doesn't merge regardless of type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try, instead, is having two configuration files like:

**src/main/resources/application.yml**

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://10.254.102.12:1111/eureka/
```

and

**src/main/resources/application-test.yml**

```
eureka:
  instance:
    appname: item-client-test
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://test-server/eureka/
logging:
  level: debug
```

and run your tests with `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test mvn test`

Spring Boot will look for `application-#{environment}` config file (so to say) and use it, inheriting from the default (`application.yml`) config file